# WPF - Wrapping a content with a grid control

Tags: wpf

I have a control with multiple grids (single column) within it. Is there any way (by code) to wrap each content (whatever it is) with another grid? For example: <Grid> <Button /> </ Grid> would be <Grid> <Grid> <Button /> </ Grid> </ Grid> after method execution, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean you want to add items as buttons to your view?

Consider using an [items control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) with a template for your items.

**[There is some basic examples here.](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/)**

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: Thanks, Stian, for the answer, but my items can be anything. I think ItemsControl would not be appropriated. The idea is to wrap each content, creating a new grid for this. As the example above: I have a XAML code:&lt;Grid&gt; &lt;Button /&gt; &lt;/ Grid&gt;. After running the application, I want an automatic wrapper, and the code would be:&lt;Grid&gt; &lt;Grid&gt; &lt;Button /&gt; &lt;/ Grid&gt; &lt;/ Grid&gt;.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how to construct a `Grid` programmatically in the [`Grid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. However, your requirements are simple and could be fulfilled like this:

```
private Grid WrapWithGrid(UIElement uiElement)
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    // Optionally set grid properties
    grid.Width = 250;
    grid.Height = 100;
    ColumnDefinition columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
    // Add element to grid
    grid.Children.Add(uiElement);
    return grid;
}
```